# Topological space $\{a,b\}$ with topology $T=\mathcal{P}\backslash\{b\}$ path connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have the topological space $A=\{a,b\}$ of two elements with the topology $T=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

> How do I prove that this is path connected?

I know that path connectedness means that for $a,b\in A$ there must be a path $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow A$ continuous such that $a=\gamma(0)$ and $b=\gamma(1)$. How do I use the topology defined here above?

Comment: Have you tried any such functions and the definition of continuous?

Comment: @MarkS. What for function can I try?

Comment: name any function between a pair of endpoints and see if it does what you want.

Comment: @MarkS. Do you mean a function like $\gamma(x)=x$?

Comment: $p,q$ must be switched for $a,b$

Comment: Since not every element of $[0,1]$ is in $\{a,b\}$, $\gamma (x)=x $ does not define a path in $A $.

Answer (score 2):

On forehand:

If $X$ is a topological space then $f:X\to A$ will be continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(S)$ is open in $X$ for each $S\in T$. For $S=\varnothing$ and $S=A$ it is evident that $f^{-1}(S)$ is open in $X$. So what remains is the demand that $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is open in $X$.

---

Prescribe $\gamma:[0,1]\to A$  by $x\mapsto a$ if $x<1$ and $x\mapsto b$ otherwise (i.e. if $x=1$).

This function satisfies $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma(1)=b$, and can be shown to be continuous.

Just observe that $\gamma^{-1}(\{a\})=[0,1)$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$.